# An array of string causing my program not to continue to run after an if-else statement - java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I am creating a simple program that gets an input from a user and outputs to .txt file. I have made some changes to my code so that whenever a user enters a variation of 'quit', 'Quit', or 'QUIT' it will break, else it will continue as normal. However when I run and enter data as normal it is not continuing as normal and stopping. Also, how would I display a printline so that when a user does type 'Quit' it would say for example

```
System.out.println("You have quit!");
```

My Code

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.file.*;



public class JavaProject {

    private static char[] input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        //variables 
        int hrs, mins;  
        String gamerName, gamerReport;
        int gameCount;
        int errorCount;

        //Main data storage arrays
        String[] gameNames = new String[100];
        int[] highScores = new int[100];
        int[] minutesPlayed = new int [100];

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //formatting for output and input
        System.out.println("////// Game Score Report Generator \\\\\\\\\\\\");
        System.out.println("     ");

        //User enters either their name or quit. Entering a name will move on to next part
        for ( ; ; )
        {
            System.out.print("Enter your Name. If you do not wish to proceed, enter 'Quit' to quit.");
            System.out.println("   ");
            gamerName = Scan.nextLine();
                if ("Quit".equals(gamerName))
                {
                    break;
                }

            for(int b = 1; b < 100; b++ ) { //this is making the code loop 100 times




        //user is given an example of input format 
        System.out.println("Input Gamer Information " + "Using Format --> Game : Achievement Score : Minutes Played");
        System.out.println("FALSE DATA FORMAT WILL CAUSE ERROR");
        System.out.println("    ");

        //another data input guide which is just above where data input is in console
        System.out.println("Game : Achievement Score : Minutes Played");
        gamerReport = Scan.nextLine();

        String[] splitUpReport = null; // an array of string
        //splitUpReport = gamerReport.split(":"); // split the text up on the colon

        //gets input, if "quit" then break
        for (int count = 0; count <= 100; count++){
            gamerReport = Scan.nextLine();

            if (gamerReport.equals("quit"))
            {
                break;
            }
            if (gamerReport.equals("Quit"))
            {
                break;
            }
            if (gamerReport.equals("QUIT"))
            {
                break;
            } 
            else  
            {
                splitUpReport = gamerReport.split(":");
            }
            System.out.println("You have quit!");
        }

        int i = 0;

        //copy data from split text into main data storage arrays 
        gameNames[i] = splitUpReport[0];
        highScores[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitUpReport[1].trim() );
        minutesPlayed[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitUpReport[2].trim());




        //output to file using a PrintWriter using a FileOutPutStream with append set to true within the printwriter constructor
        //

        try
        {

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Gaming Report Data", true));
            writer.println("Player : " + gamerName);
            writer.println();
            writer.println("--------------------------------");
            writer.println();
            String[] report = gamerReport.split(":");
            writer.println("Game: " + report[0] + ", score= " +report[1] + ", minutes played= " +report[2]);
            //writer.println("Games Played: " + splitUpReport);
            //writer.println("Total Achievement: " + highScores);
            //writer.println("Total Time: " + minutesPlayedS%60);
            writer.println();
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("File does not exist!");
        }

        }

        }
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");

    }

    public static char[] getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public static void setInput(char[] input) {
        JavaProject.input = input;
    }

}
```

my code issue

```
//gets input, if "quit" then break
            for (int count = 0; count <= 100; count++){
                gamerReport = Scan.nextLine();

                if (gamerReport.equals("quit"))
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (gamerReport.equals("Quit"))
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (gamerReport.equals("QUIT"))
                {
                    break;
                } 
                else  
                {
                    splitUpReport = gamerReport.split(":");
                }
                System.out.println("You have quit!");
            }
```

Comment: Variables in Java should start with a lowercase

Comment: `quit`, `Quit`, `QUIT`, but not `QUit`, `QuIt` etc? Maybe it'd just be easier to use `gamerReport.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `if` to `else if`. Otherwise your else is only regarding the third `if`. You can also use a single `if` with `equalsIgnoreCase`. This matches quit, Quit or QUIT.

To print a message, before each `break`, insert your `System.out.println("You have quit!");`

```
for (int count = 0; count <= 100; count++){
    gamerReport = Scan.nextLine();

    if (gamerReport.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
        System.out.println("You have quit!");
        break;
    }
    splitUpReport = gamerReport.split(":");

    gameNames[count] = splitUpReport[0];
    highScores[count] = Integer.parseInt(splitUpReport[1].trim() );
    minutesPlayed[count] = Integer.parseInt(splitUpReport[2].trim());
}
```

You also have another option, maybe more in-line with what you were trying to do.

```
// ignore the for loop
gamerReport = Scan.nextLine();

if (gamerReport.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
    System.out.println("You have quit!");
    return;
}
splitUpReport = gamerReport.split(":");
```

You should also not comment one of your scans:

```
    //another data input guide which is just above where data input is in console
    System.out.println("Game : Achievement Score : Minutes Played");
    //gamerReport = Scan.nextLine();
```

And your writer should use `splitReport`:

```
writer.println("Game: " + splitUpReport[0] + ", score= " + splitUpReport[1] + ", minutes played= " + splitUpReport[2]);
```

Comment: This still doesn't loop around to input my door and lead me to this error https://i.gyazo.com/7eae062a0e868e17506cbeae039877fa.png

Comment: That depends on your input. Print the array's elements to check what is happening.

Comment: The first 'Quit' option works with this output https://i.gyazo.com/b4d5f075e38ae19673e8b6ce2fb27506.png
when i use this code you gave me it doesn't loop around and just makes the console blank rather than let me enter another game and data again

Comment: Ah, because that is what your for originally did, if it were correct! Where I put the commentary, you should put the logic of your program. Otherwise, it just waits for 100 valid inputs before quitting the loop, and continuing somewhere else

Comment: Sorry to ask how would I input the logic?

Comment: I've added a new bit of code. Eliminate your for and use that. It quits the program when you type 'quit'. Otherwise it continues with your code.

Comment: Mine work. Maybe you closed the wrong parenthesis somewhere.

Comment: It was the parenthesis haha they are 90% of my problems! thank you for the help! so much

Comment: No problem. Just remember to upvote helpful answers and try to help out others like you in the website.

Comment: Hey, do you know how to add together data from array? So you see at the bottom it says games played, how would I add all the data entered together for
Total games played : 4 
Total Achievement points : 600
total time played : 60 mintes played (1 hour 0 minutes) 
Etc

Comment: Convert them into int or double (or date for time) and sum them.